# Machine learning for natural language processing - Custom translation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-science

Lets say I have the following very simplified training and testing observations.

**Training**

```
input: her favourite dog was a huskey and her favourite cat was a leopard
output: dog=huskey, cat=leopard

input: her favourite dog was a beagle and her favourite cat was a lion
output: dog=beagle, cat=lion

input: her favourite dog was a poodle and her favourite cat was a burmese
output: dog=poodle, cat=burmese
```

**Testing**

```
input: her favourite dog was a collie and her favourite cat was a moggie
desired output: dog=collie, cat=moggie
```

- What is the best machine learning approach in python to enable me to have the testing input translated into the desired output?
- What are the steps involved from taking this raw data to making this prediction?

From some research in the area it seems that a lot of the existing machine learning packages are around classification, regression and clustering (e.g http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), while what I am trying to do is a form of translation.

I have also looked into a few NLP packages, and the functionality falls more into the keyword identification, word type identification and sentiment analysis (e.g http://www.nltk.org/). There are also some translation packages available, but these are for pre-existing languages (http://pythonhosted.org/goslate/)

I recognise that for this particular case machine learning is thoroughly unnecessary, however in practise there will be far more complicated, different and numerous inputs to translate.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I would reformulate the problem you are trying to solve to: Given some specific **animal A** in **sentence S** find the best animal **class C**. So given sentence 1:

> her favourite dog was a huskey and her favourite cat was a leopard

and given target animal A = "huskey", you would get C = "dog" as the class; similarly when A = "leopard" you would get C = "cat".

(2) From the way you asked your question, I am assuming that you don't want to use an external dictionary or other data (where it would be relatively trivial to find collocations of class C with its associated animal species and to train a supervised classifier). So I assume you are limited to the type of data you mention. I will also assume that the class C is explicitly mentioned in each sentence.

(3) Given the data constraints, it seems likely that you will need to use syntactic information in your features. In English syntax is primarily conveyed through word order, so I would focus on these. Probably useful to apply a part-of-speech tagger to your data.

(4) For each possible target A in sentence S you will create a row of data. Thus sentence #1 has two targets A={husky, leopard}, so there will be two rows in your training data that will map to the respective classes, dog and cat.

row  Sent.   Target   F1, F2, ... FN Class

1    1       husky    ...               dog

2    1       leopard  ...               cat

(5) Include as feature the POS of the target... probably not useful in the example data you provided by would be useful for more sophisticated targets, e.g., A = "the big white husky" should map the full noun phrase to C = "dog". Given your data above the easy solution would just find the closest Noun to the left of the target.

her.d favorite.a dog.n is.v a husky.n and her.d favorite.a cat.n is.v a leopard.n

So you could have a feature F_LftClosestNoun, F_RtClosestNoun, F_ClosestNoun. Then just train your classifier on the training data and test it on the unseen data. If you provide a more realistic looking sample perhaps we can identify additional useful features.